# Django: Two Websites with Same Codebase and Separate Domain, Settings.py, WSGI File, but cannot do separate database

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi, multiple-databases, multiple-domains

I think this is likely a WSGI/Apache configuration issue.

I have a Django website served through Apache with mod_wsgi.  I am trying to run a second website from the same codebase but through a different domain, database and settings.py.

My WSGI configuration files seem to be loading the correct, separate settings.py files.  However, it seems as though the second domain is loading data from the original database and not the new one.  This is only occurring in my production environment, which has the Apache setup.

My settings.py files load common information through a file called common.py and then load in the database name.

I.e.

settings1.py

```
from common import *
DATABASES['default']['NAME'] = 'database1'
...
```

settings2.py

```
from common import *
DATABASES['default']['NAME'] = 'database2'
...
```

These settings are loaded from their own respective WSGI files:

www.domain1.com -> index1.wsgi:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/location/to/code/')
sys.path.insert(0,'/location/to/code/application')
sys.path.insert(0,'/virtual/env/python2.7/site-packages/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'application.settings1'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/location/to/.python-eggs'  

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

www.domain2.com -> index2.wsgi:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/location/to/code/')
sys.path.insert(0,'/location/to/code/application')
sys.path.insert(0,'/virtual/env/python2.7/site-packages/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'application.settings2'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/location/to/.python-eggs'  

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

As you can see, all I've done is vary the settings location.  The location of the code remains the same.  I'm convinced this part is working based on the fact that the locations of saving and loading of static files on the server has changed based on the properties of settings1.py and settings2.py.  However, the information called up the application comes from database1 even when called from www.domain2.com.  I'm not even sure how this has been possible since that database name is only available in settings1.py, not in common.py.  Anyone have any insight into this problem?

**Edit:**

I'm adding in the Apache include that directs the domains to their respective WSGI files. Note that the virtualhosts listen on localhost because I'm having NGINX listen on port 80 and forwards relevant request through to Apache.

```
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi 

NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 127.0.0.1:80

<IfModule mod_wsgi.c>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com

    ErrorDocument 500 "We are experiencing difficulties.  Please contact webmaster@domain1.com if you feel you are receiving this page in error."

    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/index1.wsgi
    Alias /static/ /path/to/static_files/static/
    WSGIDaemonProcess djangodomain1 python-path=/virtual/env/python2.7/site-packages processes=8 threads=4 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup djangodomain1
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 second"
    ExpiresByType text/js "access plus 1 second"

    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain1.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    CustomLog /path/to/logs/access_log combined
    CustomLog /path/to/domlogs/domain1.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."

    ErrorLog /path/to/logs/error_log

    ## User group1 # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup group1 group1
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        SuexecUserGroup group1 group1
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com

    ErrorDocument 500 "We are experiencing difficulties.  Please contact webmaster@domain1.com if you feel you are receiving this page in error."

    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/index2.wsgi
    Alias /static/ /path/to/static/
    WSGIDaemonProcess djangodomain2 python-path=/virtual/env/python2.7/site-packages processes=8 threads=4 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup djangodomain2
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 second"
    ExpiresByType text/js "access plus 1 second"

    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain1.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    CustomLog /path/to/logs/domain2/access_log combined
    CustomLog /path/to/domlogs/domain2.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."

    ErrorLog /path/to/logs/domain2/error_log

    ## User group1 # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup group1 group1
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        SuexecUserGroup group1 group1
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Add your mod_wsgi configuration so that can be verified.

Comment: Check that `common.py` isn't specifying a `WSGI_APPLICATION` pointing to your `settings1.py` file. This should only effect Django's built-in `runserver` command, but since this is a pretty strange situation, it's worth at least checking.

Comment: Graham, I've added the Apache configuration that processes requests on these two domains.  Orokusaki, I did a grep for WSGI_APPLICATION (and even just WSGI) inside of my codebase and didn't come up with anything.  Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [WSGIApplicationGroup](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIApplicationGroup) setting is messing you up.
I would remove it from both VirtualHost entries.

Comment: I tried removing it like you've said, I've also tried setting it to ${SERVER} so that it could vary by domain name, and neither seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after studying your configuration I am convinced that 'most likely' apache is not matching your virtualhost and is routing to the first one. This would explain why it is only occuring in the 2nd env.

Read the last stanza of this blog entry:
[Gram's Blog on setting up django](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/search/label/django) **Fallback to default VirtualHost definition.**

--- snip ---

As a failsafe to pick up such issues and ensure that requests don't unintentionally go to the wrong site, a good practice may be to ensure that the first VirtualHost that Apache encounters when reading its configuration is actually a dummy definition which doesn't equate to an actual site.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
   Deny from all
</VirtualHost>
```

--- end snip ---

Gram lists several other things that can go wrong in that document. But after carefully studying your configs.. I'm pretty sure your issue is with the virtual host request getting routed to the incorrect config.